# Test that locale works

Tags: spring, google-chrome, spring-mvc, internationalization

I am using I18 with Spring. How can I test this with a different locale. My browser language in english.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/guide", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(Locale locale){
        return locale.toString().equals("no") ? "/guide_no" : "/guide_en";
}

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
   <property name="defaultLocale" value="no"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some browser add-on that allows changing cookie values, for example [Edit This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-this-cookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en).

However, you will also need to implement some way that allows the user to change the locale, otherwise your users will always use the default locale -> no need to test anything else :)